# RSpec "retest broken tests from last time" flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Is there any way to retest previously broken tests?

So, say, I run `rspec` and several tests in different files and directories fail. 
I fix something and now I have to manually specify all files and folders I want to retest or run tests for whole project again(It takes considerable amount of time for big projets).

What I was looking for is something like a flag

```
rspec --prev-failed-only
```

I realize that such flag would require considerable amount of additional actions from rspec, like storing results of previous tests and so on. But I think it would be super convenient to me.

Is there any such(or similar) tool/gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rspec-rerun` gem does what you want : https://github.com/dblock/rspec-rerun

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/456 has a good discussion on the topic of making rspec itself be able to rerun failed tests.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Giant Robots podcast](http://giantrobots.fm/145), Sam Phippen of the core team mentioned this feature is due to be added to RSpec soon.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else finds this, a month after the question was asked (open source <3 ) [rspec 3.3 introduced](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/command-line/only-failures) the `--only-failures` option, also the delightfully handy `--next-failure` (`-n`) option.  `rspec --help` for more info.